# Mac OS X custom application view

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nsview

I've been searching Google and S.O. the last few days and am not quite sure the right question to even ask.

I'm 100% a complete noob when it comes to OS X programming.  Thought I'd try my hand at a simple utility app.  Nothing major by any means.  The programming side of things is actually already done, but skinning it is proving more difficult than I thought it would be.

What I'm trying to accomplish is something along the lines of this:
[image: custom layout]

But all I can seem to figure out how to do is this:

[image]

As you can see, I have what will become a button sort of off to the side and up in the corner (I've disabled the title bar buttons on purpose). I'm building all my views inside of Interface Builder, using Xcode 4.5.2.

Again, sorry for what is probably the most basic of questions... but what do I even start to search for?  Everything I find, I'm coming up blank.  No tutorials, no examples, nothing.  I'm assuming it's something to do with a custom view or window of some sort...   Have any of you come across some sampel code or a tutorial that would help?

Thank you greatly in advance!
:-)
- Drew

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for "cocoa custom window" turned up [this](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html). Good luck.

Comment: Hah... I literally found that about 20 minutes after I sent up the original post.  Haven't tried it out yet... though.  Actually... that post is also purely code based.  I'd like to feed it through Interface Builder as much as possible. 

Not sure if there is a way to do that though...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the noob in me really was showing through as I wasn't understanding the difference between a Window and a View.  Heh...

Using a combination of tips from this site: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/BorderlessWindow.

To a greater extent I guess by bastardizing this Round Window sample project from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/index.html

I was able to see the example the proper way to do it and get the necessary pieces migrated into my own project.

Bam!  Looks exactly as I had hoped it would...  :-)